# Raise baseline in NSTextView field editor

Tags: nstextview, nstokenfield, nstokenfieldcell

I want to manipulate the baseline when typing text in an `NSTokenField` to match the displayed tokens. To do so, I'm following the guide ["Working With the Field Editor"](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/TextEditing/Tasks/FieldEditor.html) in the documentation. There it is recommended to override the method `- (NSText *)setUpFieldEditorAttributes:(NSText *)textObj;` of the associated `NSTextFieldCell` to adjust the field editors properties before editing. Here's what I do there:

```
- (NSText *)setUpFieldEditorAttributes:(NSText *)textObj {
    textObj = [super setUpFieldEditorAttributes:textObj];
    if([textObj isKindOfClass:[NSTextView class]]) {
        NSTextView *fieldEditor = (NSTextView *)textObj;
        [fieldEditor raiseBaseline:self];
        [fieldEditor raiseBaseline:self];
        [fieldEditor raiseBaseline:self];
        NSLog(@"Raised editor baseline");
    }
    return textObj;
}
```

As I can confirm with the help of the log, the method get's called. However, the baseline doesn't change at all while editing. Also calling other methods like `[fieldEditor loosenKerning:self]` that should produce a visible result don't seem to be having any effect. What am I doing wrong here or better - how can I achieve what I want to?

Comment: `raiseBaseline:` "Raises the baseline offset of **selected text**"

Comment: This seems to answer the question. Do you have any idea how to set the baseline for the whole view while editing, not only a selection?